# Open XML How to programmatically group (shift select) sheets in Excel

Tags: c#

I am trying to programmatically group (shift select) sheets in Excel using Open XML API. I know how to do it in Interop way like:

```
String[] sheetsToBeSelected = {"Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"}; 
excel.Workbook workbook = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook; 
excel.Sheets worksheets = workbook.Worksheets; 

((excel.Sheets)worksheets.get_Item(sheetsToBeSelected)).Select();
```

Tried hard to translate it to Open XML API, but no luck. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the TabSelected property of SheetView. Here is the sample code

```
foreach(Sheet sht in myWorkBook.WorkBook.Descendants<Sheet>())
{
    WorkSheetPart wrkShtPart = (WorkSheetPart)myWorkBook.GetPartById(sht.Id);
    SheetViews shtViews = wrkShtPart.WorkSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetViews>();
    SheetView shtView = shtViews.GetFirstChild<SheetView>();
    shtView.TabSelected = null;
}
```